# JSON Response Value says Null Rest Assured

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

My JSON Response reads something like:

```
{
 "_embedded":{
   "contents": [
   {
    "data": 1234,
    "success": true, 
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

I am attempting to extract the the success message and data. However my console output keeps reading null.

Once extracting the Response here is my code that receives a Null response using Rest Assured:

```
String res = response.asString():
JsonPath js = new JsonPath(res);

String success = js.get("_embedded[0].contents[0].success");
String data = js.get("_embedded[0].contents[0].data");

System.out.println(success);
System.out.println(data);
```

My response for both success and data is null

Answer (score 4):

From your JSON sample, it looks like _embedded is not a list. _embedded[0] might return null because there is no list named _embedded when you try to extract the success value using "_embedded[0].contents[0].success".

Extract the success value by using

```
js.get("$._embedded.contents[0].success");
```

Comment: I tried removing "_embedded" however I get **Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object** new success String reads `js.get("contents[0].success")`

Comment: @mike try js.get("$._embedded.contents[0].success")

Comment: response is **java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String**

Comment: response for changing data is ***java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String***

Comment: That's because you are setting both of these values to Strings. If you change the types of success and data to their corresponding types (Boolean and Long) then you will see the values.